# Is JSON serialization and deserialization a suitable way to duplicate a hierarchy?

Tags: c#, serialization

I have a hierarchy of nodes where the relevant part of the Node class looks like this:

```
public class Node 
{
    protected Node parent;
    protected List<Node> children;

    public Node Duplicate()
    {
        string json = JsonUtility.ToJson(this);
        Node duplicate = (Node)JsonUtility.FromJson(json, GetType());
        return duplicate;
    }
}
```

(I use Unity's JsonUtility to serialize to JSON and then deserialize it. Should be the same with System.Text.Json)

Now I want to create a duplicate of a Node with all of its children, and so I do this:

```
Node duplicate = someNode.Duplicate();
```

Did I just create a deep copy of the hierarchy, or is it just another way to make a shallow copy?

Is JSON serialization and deserialization suitable for duplicating hierarchies where I want all of the data to be intact?

Comment: its a bit overkill.

Comment: @DanielA.White are you saying it will work (even though it is overkill)? I need the entire structure of the hierarchy to be preserved with no references to nodes in the old hierarchy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've definitely created a deep copy. This approach has one benefit: It works correctly. It has one drawback: Horrible performance. If that's not an issue, its simplicity is alluring.

And performance might not be an issue! It depends on your scenario.

Comment: Awesome! Deep copy was my goal here. Performance is no problem as nodes rarely are duplicated.